# Pegar ids de inputs usando for no js

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou tentando pegar o valor de 10 inputs e botá-los em um vetor de 10 casas, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso pelo for, alguém pode me ajudar a conseguir fazer com que no for a var `n[0]` por exemplo pegue o valor do `inputVetor0`?

```
var i;
function calcularMaior() {
    var n = new Array(10);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var input = "input";
        var inputNumero = "" + i.toString();
        var inputId = input.concat(inputNumero);
        n[i] = document.getElementById(inputId).innerHTML;
    }
    alert("Array 0 = " + n[0];
}
```

Código completo: https://jsfiddle.net/sf14tf8c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando pegar o `innerHTML` dos inputs quando deveria pegar o `value`:

```
n[i] = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
```

Comment: valeu mano, sou bem novato ainda, tinha me baseado num problema parecido e adaptei, por isso não entendia mto do q era pra fazer, valeu mesmo.

Comment: Dica: `innerHTML` é o que fica entre `<tag>` e `</tag>`. Percebe que inputs não têm tag de fechamento. Com inputs e selects você deve usar sempre `value` para obter o valor atual.